# Understanding command through adb shell and through code - Android

Tags: android, linux, shell, adb

I am trying to give `BATTERSTATS` permission to an app. When I run the command from a PC - it works just fine:

```
adb shell pm grant com.example.sample.myapplication android.permission.BATTERY_STATS
```

But the same `pm grant` command does not work when run from Android app:

```
java.lang.Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm grant com.example.sample.myapplication android.permission.BATTERY_STATS");
```

Does it require root permission to give this permission?
If it is so, why it does not require the device to be rooted to run it via `adb shell`?

I am new to Android, please explain a bit more clearly what is happening inside and how to proceed.

Comment: Why are you executing that at runtime? Just add the permission to the manifest

Comment: Often commands you can use in adb shell require root if you execute the command at runtime in your application. If your want to grant permissions at runtime your should read this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I have given that in my manifest, but still its not working..

Answer (score 3):

The command you run with `adb shell` gets executed with `shell(UID=2000)` user privileges. The command you run from your `java` code gets executed with your app's `UID` privileges. Thus the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer....can you explain bref.....which means that **shell(UID=2000)** having access of super user permission or what...Explore little more with some doc

Comment: I'm not very savvy with shell. Can you please clarify how to solve the issue so that the java code gets executed with UID=2000? Or would that not be possible?(As you read on my posted question) I wish to do the same with a dpm command, would changing my apps UID privileges help? if so, how would I go about doing so? Thanks

Comment: do you know why running any wm command (e.g. `wm size`) works from adb but returns `Can't find service: window` from java (instead of some permission/user error). Different users do not explain why the command fails with `can't find` instead of an permission error...